# AndroidEmulator Linux - graphic artifact after emulator update to v26.1.2

Tags: android, sdk, android-emulator, artifacts

I'm experiencing grapghical articafts (horizontal lines) on my emulator on Linux. They are visible especially when scrolling lists (for example, system settings) or on animations.

I have noticed this is caused by latest (I updated today - to version 26.1.2) emulator update from Google. After restoring Sdk/emulator folder from other machine (where update has not been applied), my emulator works fine again and I have no any graphical glitches anymore.

Can anybody confirm the issue on Linux? My graphic card is intel, artiffacts are there no matter if I chhoose hardware or software rendering in my avd settings.

Maybe need to report bug to Google?